# .each and .text to store a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery to loop through `li` elements of a `div` and grab the text of those elements.

I have tried this code:

```
var liText = $('#4441437 li').each(function() {  
   $( this ).text()
});

console.log(liText);
```

When I do this I see this:

```
Object[li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li]
```

I realize that this is a jQuery object that is returned.

My question is how do I store just the text in a variable for each `li` element within a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store text values in Array, or store all content in one variable as one string (not a good idea). I will post both versions:

```
var contentArr = [];
var fullContent = '';
var liText = $('#4441437 li').each(function() {  
    contentArr.push($(this).text());
    fullContent += $(this).text() + ' ';
});

console.log(contentArr);
console.log(fullContent);
```

Here is  example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwsmaster/V3nSP/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

**js**

```
var liText = $('#4441437 li').map(function() {  
    return $( this ).text()
}).get();

console.log(liText);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rXQA/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
var liText = [];
 $('#4441437 li').each(function() {
    liText.push($( this ).text() 
 }); 
 console.log(liText);
```